# How to apply shape to mesh as vertices?

Tags: mesh

I'm modeling a wall mounted light switch. I want to add a screw to the top and bottom of the switch. To accomplish this, I've tried to shrink wrap a circle to the mesh and merge the circle to the primary mesh, but the vertices of the circle do not override the vertices of the primary mesh. Basically, I want to apply a circular set of vertices to the primary mesh then delete the face of the circle in order to make a hole. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

**Use the Boolean modifier.**

I will demonstrate it on a plane, and will cut a hole in it with a cylinder.

[image]

Select the plane, go to your *Outliner* and go to the *Modifier Properties* tab. Click *Add Modifier* and under the *Generate* column, select *Boolean*.

Set the modifier to the *Difference* mode, select the cylinder with the *Object* eyedropper tool and set the *Solver* to *Fast*.

[image]

Click the little dropdown arrow and *Apply*.

[image]

Here's the resulting mesh in edit mode: (you can delete or hide the cylinder now)

[image]